# C read input until 0

Tags: arrays, c

this program is trying to convert decimal into binary number. I want the program to print the outputs all at once rather than after every input
expected output:

```
31
-1
0

0000 0000 0001 1111
1111 1111 1111 1111
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

My output:

```
Enter a number to convert to binary: 31
00000000000011111
Enter a number to convert to binary: -1
11111111111111111
Enter a number to convert to binary: 0
00000000000000000
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert(int num){
    int bit;
    for (int i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        bit = num >> i;

        if (bit & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int num = 1; 

    // reads input until 0 is reached
    while (num != 0){
        printf("Enter a number to convert to binary: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        convert(num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you haven't shown any attempt to use an array. Do you know how to declare an array? How to read into an array? Iterate an array? etc. Please explain what specifically you need help with.

Comment: First of all, do you know about functions? Then I suggest you do the whole "converts to binary in 16 bits" bit in a separate function. I suggest that because then it's easy to call it *inside* the `while` loop you have, which is the correct place to do it. Of course, it requires a slight change in logic for the `num != 0` check.

Comment: Secondly, you should *always* check what [`scanf` ***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). I can easily get your input loop to become an infinite loop by pressing the end-of-file key sequence.

Comment: I put the `for loop` in a function, but now it prints the output after every input rather than printing all at once.

Comment: Okay, I kind of misunderstood that part. Then yes you need an array, store all numbers in the array, and use a separate loop to print the results. Using a function is still a good idea though. Now for the array itself, do you want to have a fixed-sized array which can become full? Or do you want to use a dynamic array which is extended as needed? Once you have decided that, then either read about arrays in your text-book, or read about pointers and dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create an array to store all the input values, then you should call the function from a separate function instead of the while loop. Because if you do it inside the while loop it will print the output after every iteration of the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void convert(int num){
    int bit,i;
    for ( i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        bit = num>>i;
        if (bit & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int num = 1,i=0,j;
    int arr[999]; // a very large array since size is unknown. you could also dynamically allocate.

    // reads input until 0 is reached
    while (num != 0){
        printf("Enter a number to convert to binary: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        arr[i++]=num;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Call your function here, where `i` is the number of input enter (the size)
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        convert(arr[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in multiple ways but storing all input values in an array is probably the simplest solution.

A very simple approach:

```
#define MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_INPUT_VALUES 32

int main()
{
    int num = 1; 
    int cnt = = 0;
    int arr[MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_INPUT_VALUES];

    // reads input until 0 is reached
    while (num != 0 && cnt < MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_INPUT_VALUES)
    {
        printf("Enter a number to convert to binary: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) exit(1);
        arr[cnt] = num;
        ++cnt;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        convert(arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The "bad" thing with this approach is the hard coded limit for the number of input values. To solve that you can use dynamic memory allocation so that the "array" can grow in size at run time. Like:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 1; 
    int cnt = = 0;
    int* arr = NULL;

    // reads input until 0 is reached
    while (num != 0)
    {
        int *tmp = realloc(arr, (cnt + 1) * sizeof *tmp);  // Increase "array" size
        if (tmp == NULL) exit(1);                          // Check for success
        arr = tmp;                                         // Save pointer to memory
        printf("Enter a number to convert to binary: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) exit(1);
        arr[cnt] = num;
        ++cnt;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        convert(arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice: The above code doesn't do any "nice error handling". To keep the code simple it just exits when something "bad" happens. In real code you should replace the `exit(1)` statement with some better error handling code.